# Python Problem of Web scraping Asos Error

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to scrape some data from Asos but I get stuck. Thanks for your help, I can now scrape the name of the product. However, the same pattern doesn't work when it comes to scraping both the RRP price and the current price. Here is my code. Hope someone can point out my error. Thank you!

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
import requests


headers = {
        'authority': 'www.asos.com',
        'method': 'GET',
        'path': '/us/hollister/hollister-v-neck-knitted-sweater/prd/14148890',
        'scheme': 'https',
        'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'accept-language': 'de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
        'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
        'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36',
}
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False

url = "https://www.asos.com/us/hollister/hollister-v-neck-knitted-sweater/prd/14148890"
html = requests.get(url, headers = headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
wrappers = soup("div",{"class":"grid-row rendered"})

for wrap in wrappers:
    
    print(wrap.find("span",{"data-id":"rrp-price"})["class"])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified two main parts in your code and it's working now.

BS4Parsing: Here you need to iterate over every found "div" and use find() to get the "h1" element. Furthermore "aside-content" is the "id" not the "class" of the div's you are scraping.

Bypassing potential Bot Prevention: The program is now imitating a chrome browser. You can read out the request headers in chrome developer tools and use them as the header for the python requests. There are also python module for this purpose called "fake-useragent" btw. Since your operation timed out I think the main solution is the second part of my modifications.

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
import requests


headers = {
        'authority': 'www.asos.com',
        'method': 'GET',
        'path': '/us/hollister/hollister-v-neck-knitted-sweater/prd/14148890',
        'scheme': 'https',
        'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'accept-language': 'de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
        'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
        'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36',
}


ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
url = "https://www.asos.com/us/hollister/hollister-v-neck-knitted-sweater/prd/14148890"
html = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
wraps = soup("div",{"id":"aside-content"})

for wrap in wraps:

    print(wrap.find("h1"))
```

Output: <h1>Hollister v neck knitted sweater</h1>

Solution to your new question:
You need to request the asos api directly, since the website uses xhr to generate the price html dynamically.

```
response = requests.get("https://www.asos.com/api/product/catalogue/v3/stockprice?productIds=14148890&store=US&currency=USD&keyStoreDataversion=j42uv2x-26", headers=headers)

response_json = json.loads(response.text)

print(response_json['productPrice']['current']['text'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Would you mind to check my code above once more? The same method does not work when I want to scrape the price.@Lukas Räpple

Comment: @chunghimlau If my first answer was the solution to your first question, then please mark it as the answer or give an up vote:) This would be nice. Now to your new question: The data you want to parse is generated by xhr. You won't be able to get the data with bs4. Instead request the source api directly. I edited my post with the solution to your new question. Please don't make a whole new question out of your old question, because your new and second question cover differently technologies and scrping techniques. Instead just post another question and leave the old as it was.